# Everyplay issue on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone-6-plus, everyplay

I have an app previously published on iOS using Everyplay.

Currently updating the app to iOS 8 and iPhone 6 support.

The app is a custom OpenGL engine using GLKit.
It has been updated to support native resolution and running at 1920x1080 on iPhone 6 plus.

During capture there will be warning messages every 5 seconds saying:

```
-[EveryplayCapture encoderNewAudioSample:timestamp:asbd:frames:] error appending audio samples
```

Once recording is finished and I launch the interface to share the replay using:

```
[[Everyplay sharedInstance] playLastRecording];
```

A black view pops up with a constant progress / waiting animation. At this point its not possible to navigate back to the application so its basically frozen.

A message is displayed in the debugger output at the time of trying to share the replay.
There was an error playing the video:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo=0x16724f00 {NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this media.}
```

This issue is not occuring on my iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0):

Recording against the new iPhone 6 native resolutions causes issues with older SDKs, but then again there's always few things to fix when new iOS/Xcode major release combo gets out. :)

The first release capable of supporting the new iPhone 6 native resolutions is SDK 1.8.3/build 1830 (current is 1.8.4/1840), have you upgraded?

An all new videoplayer is planned to get released along the next major release, it should handle certain error cases better along along with new UI design

Comment: The Everyplay SDK build is 1840. I think I will try integrating Everyplay into a plain XCode generated GLKit sample to see if it's something else I might be doing in my app that causes it.

Comment: I've done a few more tests. I disabled music in my app that was using AVAudioPlayer and now the problem has gone away.

Comment: We continued to iterate the issue with Derek through mail and eventually found nothing to retrigger the issue after some desktop/device reboots. It's possible that a device state with mediaserverd process got quirky when used with older than 1.8.4 SDK first, continued to caused problems after SDK upgrade and got fixed after device reboot.